# websocket send message from the server to all clients

Tags: java, java-websocket

I want to send a message to all active clients.

```
@OnMessage
public void onMessage(String message, Session session) {
    switch (message) {
    case "latencyEqualize":

        for (Session otherSession : session.getOpenSessions()) {
            RemoteEndpoint.Basic other = otherSession.getBasicRemote();
            String data = "Max latency = "
                    + LatencyEqualizer.getMaxLatency(latencies);            
            try {
                other.sendText(data);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
        break;
    default:

        RemoteEndpoint.Basic other = session.getBasicRemote();          
        try {
            other.sendText(message);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Something is wrong with this code. When i send message "latencyEqualize" from the first client the server answers only to the same client. Other clients don't receive message "Max latency = 15". But when the second client sends to server any message, he recieves back "Max latency = 15". And all future calls to server return the message from previous call.

Is there a way to avoid this. I want all clients get "Max latency" message when one of them send "latencyEqualize" message to the server.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason why only one client receives your message is that `session` variable contains connection only of that client who sent you message.

To send your message to all clients, store their connections in some collection (for example, `ArrayList<Session>`) in `onOpen()` method, and then iterate though that collection to get connections of all of your clients

Comment: http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/java-ee-html5-websockets-with-multiple-clients-example